# Data Consistency with Data Mapper Pattern

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, triggers

I'm developing a web application for scheduling logistical distribution. I'm using Java, JSF 2.0 and Oracle-XE as database.
In Oracle-XE, I have implemented sequences and triggers to auto-increment the ID of some attributes.
My problem is, if I execute the application for instance to add a new customer, then I need to retrieve the incremented ID from the database and save it in my customer object afterwards. Is there another way to get the incremented ID from the database directly? I don't like the solution with SELECTing the ID from the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are issuing SQL directly against the database via JDBC (if you are using an object-relational mapping layer, the API probably supports something similar), you can use the RETURNING clause during an INSERT.  Something like

```
INSERT INTO table_name( column1, column2, ... , columnN )
  VALUES( :1, :2, ... , :N )
  RETURNING key_column INTO :new_key
```

That will return the value that the trigger populated for the `KEY_COLUMN` column into the `:new_key` bind variable.

Comment: Is it possible to assign the RETURNED key into a variable, for example an integer?